# Sorting a NotesDocumentCollection based on a date field in SSJS

Tags: sorting, collections, treemap, xpages

Using Server side javascript, I need to sort a NotesDcumentCollection based on a field in the collection containing a date when the documents was created or any built in field when the documents was created.

It would be nice if the function could take a sort option parameter so I could put in if I want the result back in ascending or descending order.

the reason I need this is because I use database.getModifiedDocuments() which returns an unsorted notesdocumentcollection. I need to return the documents in descending order.

The following code is a modified snippet from openNTF which returns the collection in ascending order.

```
function sortColByDateItem(dc:NotesDocumentCollection, iName:String) {
try{    
    var rl:java.util.Vector = new java.util.Vector();
    var tm:java.util.TreeMap = new java.util.TreeMap();
    var doc:NotesNotesDocument = dc.getFirstDocument();

    while (doc != null) {
        tm.put(doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray(iName)[0].toJavaDate(), doc);
        doc = dc.getNextDocument(doc);
    }
    var tCol:java.util.Collection = tm.values();
    var tIt:java.util.Iterator  = tCol.iterator();
    while (tIt.hasNext()) {
       rl.add(tIt.next());
    }
    return rl;  
}catch(e){

}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you construct the TreeMap, pass a Comparator to the constructor. This allows you to define custom sorting instead of "natural" sorting, which by default sorts ascending. Alternatively, you can call descendingMap against the TreeMap to return a clone in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very expensive methodology if you are dealing with large number of documents. I mostly use NotesViewEntrycollection (always sorted according to the source view) or view navigator.

For large databases, you may use a view, sorted according to the modified date and navigate through entries of that view until the most recent date your code has been executed (which you have to save it somewhere).

For smaller operations, Tim's method is great!

Comment: The getModfiedDocuments() method is not available at view level

Comment: You don't need to have. Sort the view by desc. modified time, start from the first row and go down until the last run of your code...